# Cannot catch custom std::runtime_error

Tags: c++, exception, clang

In my code I throw my custom file_error exception, which is derived from std::runtime_error. In a different module I catch exceptions for that operation and want to handle my file_error like this:

```
try
{
  base::create_directory(INVALID_NAME, 0700);
  ...
}
catch (const base::file_error &exc)
{
   ...
}
catch(std::runtime_error &exc)
{
    ...
}
catch(std::exception &exc)
{
  ...
}
```

file_error is declared as:

```
namespace base {
class file_error : public std::runtime_error
{
  int sys_error_code;
  public:
    file_error(const std::string &text, int err);

    error_code code();
    int sys_code();
};
}
```

However, the catch branch for file_error is never triggered. Either I end up in the runtime_error branch or, if I remove that, in the exception branch.

However, this works fine in Linux + Win (gcc, VS) while it does not work on Mac (clang). Any idea what could be wrong here?

**Update:**

Here's the lldb output when I reach the runtime_error branch:

```
(lldb) p exc
(const base::file_error) $0 = {
  std::runtime_error = {
    __imp_ = (__imp_ = 0x0000000000000000)
  }
  sys_error_code = 13923331
}
```

That clearly indicates the exception is indeed of type base::file_error. It's just not catched in its associated catch block.

**Update 2:**

Declaring an own error based on file_error in the same file as the test code above like this:

```
class test_error : base::file_error {

public:
  test_error(const std::string &s) : base::file_error(s, 0) {};
};
```

allows me to catch it in a test_error block and in a catch-all block, but not in base::file_error, std::runtime_error or std::exception blocks. Weird.

**Update 3:**

After a lot of experimenting I now think this is a type mismatch issue, similar to the ODR-violation but a different kind. The types in the dylib and in the test app are not considered the same and hence the exception is not catched, unless I throw that base::file_error exeption directly in the test code.

Comment: That might suggest that you have an ODR violation: multiple definitions of `base::runtime_error` are used by different parts of your application.

Comment: Nope, I checked all code. Just a single definition exists.

Comment: Try linking using gold with `--detect-odr-violations` command line option.

Comment: Why would it show as `const` in the debugger whereas your exception handlers catch exceptions by reference to non-const?

Comment: That's just because I tried with various combinations and don't want to constantly update the question text. Originally the catch block is for `(const base::file_error &exc)`.

Comment: That suggests you might miss something else in your question, or the posted code is not what you actually see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is to avoid using the compiler option `-fvisibility=hidden` (or make it default) in the test application. Read more about this here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options. In particular this part:

> Note that -fvisibility does affect C++ vague linkage entities. This
>   means that, for instance, an exception class that is be thrown between
>   DSOs must be explicitly marked with default visibility so that the
>   ‘type_info’ nodes are unified between the DSOs.
>
> An overview of these techniques, their benefits and how to use them is
>   at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility.

Answer (score 4):

```
class test_error : base::file_error
```

> allows me to catch it in a test_error block and in a catch-all block, but not in base::file_error, std::runtime_error or std::exception blocks.

Your exception classes need to derive **publicly** from base exception classes. Otherwise you won't be able to catch them via the base class:

```
class test_error : public base::file_error
```

Comment: Good catch. This at least explains why I couldn't catch the test error as file_error, which now works. Just the original question is still open.